# GCM not Working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am learning **GCM(Google cloud Messaging)**
I Completed Following steps

**1** - Activated and Obtained a Key for browser apps

**2** - added  following in manifest

*Uses permission* :  com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Created permission to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the Android application's messages

Created a receiver for com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE, with the category set as applicationPackage. The receiver should require the com.google.android.c2dm.SEND permission

**3** – in receiver

```
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
        GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
```

**GcmMessageHandler** it’s a Intend Service to show a notification on receive gcm message.following is onHandleIntent Method in **GcmMessageHandler**.

```
@Override

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    handler.post(new Runnable() {


        @Override

        public void run() {

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());

            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            mBuilder.setContentTitle("GCM Received");

            mBuilder.setContentText("GCM Message");

            manager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


        }

    });


    Log.i("app", "Received ");

    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}
```

**4** - MainActivity-to register and get clint ID, from log cat I copyed that id.

**5** - from browser I make post request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send with authorization,content-type,and registration_ids.

Its gets success message.
But my device not showing notification.

Comment: Can you post your full manifest? Or at least the parts relevant to GCM?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

Comment: Is `com.example.test` your app's package? Which package is the broadcast receiver in?

Comment: <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 
                <category android:name="com.example.test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmMessageHandler" />

Comment: yes ,its my app pakage @Eran

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet with WiFi or mobile data?

Comment: mobile data. i also tried with wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone,

Actually my program is correct. I think it’s a problem with my phone. 
(I can’t receive messages from Facebook messenger also,)

but Today morning  I surprised, I got every messages from  my test app(message that I send 2 days ago), Facebook ,etc.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -2):

Follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22069347/3360307) easy tutorial to send and receive push nothification in Android.
And check package naming and `AndroidManifest.xml` file configured correctly as explained in this example and set receiver like this:

```
    <receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="your package name here" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: this is not an answer - comment at best.